# Canceling unwind action associated to a button in iOS

Tags: ios

I had this *delete* button which is connected to an unwind action. There is also an IBAction associated with this button. So after user clicks this button, it is supposed to delete some data and unwind to the previous scene. Then I added some condition checking in the IBAction. So if the condition is met, go ahead and delete data and do the unwind. Otherwise, don't delete anything and stays in current scene (don't unwind). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it just like you would for a forward segue. Delete the unwind segue connection from the button, and remake the segue from the controller instead. Give the unwind segue an identifier, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` from your button method if the condition is met.

Comment: Thank you. This solution perfectly solves the problem.